# SQL SUM on rows and calculations not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I have the following Diagram of my DB.
[image: E-R Diagram]
I want to create an invoice, based on a Customer, in a specific date range.

My SQL :

```
SELECT 
    Treatment.Treatment_Date, 
    Salutation.Value as Title,
    Customer.Firstname,
    Customer.Lastname,
    Address.Value as Street, 
    Postal.Postal, 
    Postal.City, 
    Patient.Name as AnimalName,
    TreatmentType.Type as Treatment,
    Treatment.Price,
    Tax.Value as Tax,
    SUM(Treatment.Price) as TotalExTax,
    SUM(Treatment.Price * Tax.Value / 100) as TotalTax,
    SUM(Treatment.Price) + (SUM(Treatment.Price * Tax.Value / 100)) as TotalPrice

FROM Treatment
INNER JOIN Patient ON Treatment.Patient_FK = Patient.ID
INNER JOIN AnimalType ON Patient.Type_FK = AnimalType.ID
INNER JOIN Customer ON Patient.Owner_FK = Customer.ID
INNER JOIN TreatmentType ON Treatment.TreatmentType_FK = TreatmentType.ID
INNER JOIN Salutation ON Customer.Salutation_FK = Salutation.ID
INNER JOIN Address ON Customer.Address_FK = Address.ID
INNER JOIN Postal ON Address.Postal_FK = Postal.Postal
INNER JOIN Tax ON Treatment.Tax_FK = Tax.ID

WHERE Customer.ID = 151 AND Treatment.Treatment_Date between '11/12/2014 00:00:00 AM' and '12/12/2014 12:00:00 PM'
```

My Issues lies in my SUM.
TotalExTax, should calculate the total price of all the "treatments"
TotalTax, should give me the tax of the total (25%)
TotalPrice, should give me the price including tax.

BUT...
It just seems to give me random errors..
Right now it just says:

```
Error 8120: Column 'Treatment.Treatment_Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

I have googled the issue, and as far as i can see it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing an aggregation like this you need to have a GROUP BY, which you can put below your WHERE clause

```
GROUP BY
    Treatment.Treatment_Date, 
    Salutation.Value,
    Customer.Firstname,
    Customer.Lastname,
    Address.Value, 
    Postal.Postal, 
    Postal.City, 
    Patient.Name,
    TreatmentType.Type,
    Treatment.Price,
    Tax.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    Treatment.Treatment_Date, 
    Salutation.Value as Title,
    Customer.Firstname,
    Customer.Lastname,
    Address.Value as Street, 
    Postal.Postal, 
    Postal.City, 
    Patient.Name as AnimalName,
    TreatmentType.Type as Treatment,
    Treatment.Price,
    Tax.Value as Tax,
    SUM(Treatment.Price) as TotalExTax,
    SUM(Treatment.Price * Tax.Value / 100) as TotalTax,
    SUM(Treatment.Price) + (SUM(Treatment.Price * Tax.Value / 100)) as TotalPrice

FROM Treatment
INNER JOIN Patient ON Treatment.Patient_FK = Patient.ID
INNER JOIN AnimalType ON Patient.Type_FK = AnimalType.ID
INNER JOIN Customer ON Patient.Owner_FK = Customer.ID
INNER JOIN TreatmentType ON Treatment.TreatmentType_FK = TreatmentType.ID
INNER JOIN Salutation ON Customer.Salutation_FK = Salutation.ID
INNER JOIN Address ON Customer.Address_FK = Address.ID
INNER JOIN Postal ON Address.Postal_FK = Postal.Postal
INNER JOIN Tax ON Treatment.Tax_FK = Tax.ID

WHERE Customer.ID = 151 AND Treatment.Treatment_Date between '11/12/2014 00:00:00 AM' and '12/12/2014 12:00:00 PM'
group by Treatment.Treatment_Date, 
    Salutation.Value,
    Customer.Firstname,
    Customer.Lastname,
    Address.Value, 
    Postal.Postal, 
    Postal.City, 
    Patient.Name,
    TreatmentType.Type,
    Treatment.Price,
    Tax.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

`SUM` is an aggregation that works in pair with the `GROUP BY` clause. You can't sum some columns if you don't also describe which columns should not be squeezed.

Add a `GROUP BY` clause containing all columns that should not be aggregated and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Add group by

```
SELECT 
    Treatment.Treatment_Date, 
    Salutation.Value as Title,
    Customer.Firstname,
    Customer.Lastname,
    Address.Value as Street, 
    Postal.Postal, 
    Postal.City, 
    Patient.Name as AnimalName,
    TreatmentType.Type as Treatment,
    Treatment.Price,
    Tax.Value as Tax,
    SUM(Treatment.Price) as TotalExTax,
    SUM(Treatment.Price * Tax.Value / 100) as TotalTax,
    SUM(Treatment.Price) + (SUM(Treatment.Price * Tax.Value / 100)) as TotalPrice

FROM Treatment
INNER JOIN Patient ON Treatment.Patient_FK = Patient.ID
INNER JOIN AnimalType ON Patient.Type_FK = AnimalType.ID
INNER JOIN Customer ON Patient.Owner_FK = Customer.ID
INNER JOIN TreatmentType ON Treatment.TreatmentType_FK = TreatmentType.ID
INNER JOIN Salutation ON Customer.Salutation_FK = Salutation.ID
INNER JOIN Address ON Customer.Address_FK = Address.ID
INNER JOIN Postal ON Address.Postal_FK = Postal.Postal
INNER JOIN Tax ON Treatment.Tax_FK = Tax.ID

WHERE Customer.ID = 151 AND Treatment.Treatment_Date between '11/12/2014 00:00:00 AM' and '12/12/2014 12:00:00 PM'

group by Treatment.Treatment_Date, 
    Salutation.Value as Title,
    Customer.Firstname,
    Customer.Lastname,
    Address.Value as Street, 
    Postal.Postal, 
    Postal.City, 
    Patient.Name as AnimalName,
    TreatmentType.Type as Treatment,
    Treatment.Price,
    Tax.Value as Tax,
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the customer Id with the sum of the values you need to a tempory table and 
join the tempory table with rest of the tables as you wanted.

```
   Select * into #CutomerTreatments
From

(
SELECT 
Customer.ID
    SUM(Treatment.Price) as TotalExTax,
    SUM(Treatment.Price * Tax.Value / 100) as TotalTax,
    SUM(Treatment.Price) + (SUM(Treatment.Price * Tax.Value / 100)) as TotalPrice

FROM Treatment
INNER JOIN Patient ON Treatment.Patient_FK = Patient.ID
INNER JOIN Customer ON Patient.Owner_FK = Customer.ID
INNER JOIN Tax ON Treatment.Tax_FK = Tax.ID

WHERE Customer.ID = 151 AND Treatment.Treatment_Date between '11/12/2014 00:00:00 AM' and '12/12/2014 12:00:00 PM'
GROUP BY Customer.ID
) custTreat
```

**SELECT * from custTreat**